# How to display generated trx files in Jenkins WEB GUI?

Tags: jenkins, trx

I have a bunch of test result files (`*.trx`) after build is complete in directory `TestResults`.

Is it possible to display those test results in Jenkins? How?
I tried MSTest Jenkins plugin but it allows only one `trx` file per job :(

`*.trx` files are generated after each build and named with the date they are created: `YYYY_MM_DD.HH_mm_ss.TRX` thus names are constantly changing (after each re-build).

Any ideas how to display those test results in Jenkins?

Comment: I have figured out ;) I just have to insert "server\TestResults\\*.trx" in field "Test report TRX file".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Artifact Deployer Plugin of the Jenkins: [ArtifactDeployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [xUnit plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit/) in conjunction with the [MSTest plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mstest/).  Sample usage -

```
xunit(
    [MSTest(deleteOutputFiles: true,
            failIfNotNew: true,
            pattern: '*.trx',
            skipNoTestFiles: false,
            stopProcessingIfError: true)
    ])
```

Note, this expects that your trx files are in the root of your workspace.  If they aren't you'll need to copy them into there.